# create a range of years without using the range method

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Is there another way to produce this array with code that does not use the range method?

Here is and example of what im looking for but using the range method.

`const years = range(1990, getYear(new Date()) + 1, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this by writing your own function

```js
    const generateDates = (startYear) => {
        let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear(), years = [];
        startYear = startYear || 1980;  
        while ( startYear <= currentYear ) {
            years.push(startYear++);
        }   
        return years;
    }
    
    console.log( generateDates(2019-20));
```